# A specific quotient homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}$

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $\Gamma=\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ be the group of strictly positive reals, endowed with the usual multiplication. Let $X=\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$. I already showed that 
$$ \Gamma \times X \rightarrow X, (r,x)\mapsto rx$$
(the usual multiplication of vectors $x$ by scalars $r$) defines an action of $\Gamma$ on $X$. Now i have to prove that $X/ \Gamma$ is homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}$. I have no clue why this is true, so I don't even know how to start. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you mean $X/\Gamma$, the quotient of $X$ by the group action?  Hint: Think of $S^{n-1}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and show that in each equivalence class of $X/\Gamma$, there is exactly one element of $S^{n-1}$.

Comment: oh yes sorry! I'll edit my question

Comment: Hmm.. why is that true?

Comment: What do the equivalence classes of $X/\Gamma$ look like? Try to draw them, for $n=1$ and $2$, and imagine them for $n=3$. Then you should start to get close to an answer.

Comment: I just drew them, and intuitively, I know now this is true, thank you! This is already helping, but I still am stuck with writing it mathematically correct.. Can you help me?

Comment: @Arthur I still don't understand it exactly :( I hope you would like to help me further with this!